# blockui overlay not covering whole page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am using blockui for "Wait ... loading" pop up. It is working fine, but has one small issue: the overlay is covering only captured screen, not scroll window. If I scroll right, the width is not fully covered (but height is covered fully).

I have only width has problem.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery('#myAlert').click(function () {
            jQuery.blockUI({ message: '<center> <img src="/_layouts/1033/styles/ajax-loaderbar.gif" alt="Loading.." />
                <br />  <font size="2" face="Arial" >
                <b> Please wait... </b></font></center><br /> 
                <font size="2" face="Arial" ><b>while we load all your information.</b></font>'});
        });
    });
</script>
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The blocking element should be an immediate child of the  BODY tag.  It should be nested like this:

```
<html>
 <!-- etc -->
 <body>
  <div id="domMessage"></div>
  ...
```

And not this:

```
<html>
<!-- etc -->
 <body>
  <div id="some-other-div">
   <div id="domMessage"></div>
  </div>
...
```

Comment: I dont have div tag... all in message only.

Comment: Ah.  Try removing the `<center>` tag.